# How can I exclude a specific part of a URL in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

My MVC2 site sometimes redirects to a less desirable path:

http://mydomain.com/wwwroot/Controller/Action

I want to remove 'wwwroot/' anytime it is in the path.

It should be noted that this is not always in the path, I am not sure why it happens, and with or without the 'wwwroot/', the controller returns the correct view.

How can I filter this out of the route?

Comment: How is the redirect performed in your code?

Comment: It seems to happen whenever a link is generated by the link helpers like ActionLinks or paging controls.

Comment: I think that this is a IIS configuration issue. You should not create another virtual directory if your site root is already `c:\wwwroot` because when you create a site it already has a virtual directory. So if you deploy your application at the site root you don't need a virtual directory or you are adding another level in your urls.

Comment: I am on a hosting provider. I don't have control over this.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to bring this problem to their attention. That's not much that you could do in your application. You have done your job well: you have used helpers. The fact that they prepend your urls with `wwwroot` means that there's a virtual directory pointing to this location.

Comment: The application is in a virtual directory called wwwroot. It is set up as the application root.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that there is no way to stop the helpers from returning the 'wwwroot' or redirecting anything with the wwwroot to the URL without it.

Comment: Currently testing solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364637/asp-net-mvc-on-godaddy-not-working-not-primary-domain-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the URL seems to have solved my issue:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
<match url=".*" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

[Article](http://blog.boyet.com/blog/blog/solution-for-asp-net-routing-on-godaddy-shared-hosting/)